# [Neo4j] Impermanet database stored in filesystem

Tags: unit-testing, neo4j

there's a problem with my Neo4j-Test-Setup-Environment and the org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase...
I have a class, TestGraphPopulator, for setting up some dummy data for my unit tests.

Because of adding, delete, update operations in my tests, I populate the graph in every test case in init-method annotated via @Before.

But there is some really strange behavior sometimes.
Some of my test fail, because there are more or less entities as expected. In a second, or third, etc. run, everything is fine, ..or not.

AND, in my /target directory of my project, there is a folder \target\test-data\impermanent-db with all the Neo4J database data...

I'm not sure of what my problem results of, but should NOT ImpermanentGraphDatabase only reside in memory??

For me, it looks like a bug, could anyone share some experience?? This seems very important to me, and maybe others...

Thanks a lot in advance!
Markus

P.S.:
Neo4J 1.8, Spring Data Neo4J 2.1 ..

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed what has happened to me, too.  It is [confirmed](https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/874) to be a problem, and was recently fixed.  I have confirmed that no files are created when I use 1.9-SNAPSHOT.